# Ember. Keep selections from dropdown menu when user refreshes website

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a dropdown menu in an ember component. When the user selects an option, the component sends an action to the route, and the route changes an attribute in a controller and makes a transitionToRoute to a different url.

Example:

rootpath= www.example.com

User selects candy. Url => www.example.com/candy

After candy,User selects kitkat. => www.example/candy/kitkat.

If the user refreshes the website or shares the url, the dropdown menu appears unselected. 
I know that using query params fixes this, but I don't want to use query params.

Any idea how can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be stateless? How about cookies?

Comment: Not sure,I think it should be stateless.For example, If it's the first time that the user enters the website and types www.example/candy/kitkat, it should display the options selected in the dropdown menu

Comment: Well, I believe you could use a service that would distinguish what to do with the dropdown. If you don't want to use query parameters, you will probably have to use cookies, because AFAIK you lose current app state by a full page refresh.

Comment: Why not use dynamic segments? candy/kitkat look like unique identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use window.location on initialization. And extract last part out of it. Then find the following from you select data and set it as selection.

Something like this

```
....
this._super(...arguments);
var fullURL = window.location.href; // www.example.com/candy
var splittedURL = fullURL.split('/'); 
var lastPart = Ember.get(splittedURL, 'lastObject'); // candy.
var chocolateData = this.get('selectMenuContent');
var toSetOnInit = chocolateData.findBy('value', lastPart);
this.set('myChocolateSelection', toSetOnInit);
...
```

Comment: I'm trying to write this in my controller. If I define splittedUrl as an attribute of the controller, how can I access it from another attribute?

Comment: @Wesley What do you mean by another attribute? Like another route or something?